# Geometry column isn't visible in the attribute table in QGIS while it is in Python?

Tags: python, attribute-table, geometry

This code turns a dissolved shapefile to singlepart but the geometry column although it can be shown in Python when I exported as a shp and imported in QGIS the geometry column is not there. What should I do?

```
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd


def multi2single(dissolved):
    gpdf_singlepoly = gpdf[gpdf.geometry.type == 'Polygon']
    gpdf_multipoly = gpdf[gpdf.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon']

    for i, row in gpdf_multipoly.iterrows():
        Series_geometries = pd.Series(row.geometry)
        df = pd.concat([gp.GeoDataFrame(row, crs=gpdf_multipoly.crs).T]*len(Series_geometries), ignore_index=True)
        df['geometry']  = Series_geometries
        gpdf_singlepoly = pd.concat([gpdf_singlepoly, df])

    gpdf_singlepoly.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    return gpdf_singlepoly
```

here is the call:

```
multi2single(dissolved)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shapefiles don't have a geometry column as such, they store the geometries in the `.shp` file while the rest of the attributes are stored in the `.dbf` file.

So while in Python (and other languages) you can consider the geometry to be "just another" attribute when it comes to storage that may not be the case, depending on your output format.

I believe that QGis will never show the geometry in the attribute table as there is little benefit to viewing the geometry in that format, when it is showing you them on the map.

Comment: no its very useful when your trying to interact with a file and need to confirm the name of a column

Comment: if it is a shapefile then the geometry column must be called `the_geom`